# Jmeter project documentation

Tags: jmeter

We have been using the Jmeter for the API's functional and performance test activities.

Is there a possibility to generate the documentation (similar java docs, API docs) for the JMX projects that we have been developing?

Comment: Hi @chary-chelloji, I’m looking the answer to this question since I’m interested in such tools as well. Did you find a solution? Do you still interested in it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Each JMeter's [Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) has "Comments" section which can be used for explanation of what this element is for:

   [image]
2. It's possible to create a JMeter Test Plan using Java language and [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html), see [JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-command-line) for more details. There is also [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/) sample project you can use as a reference, normal [JavaDoc](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html) will be available out of the box
3. There is [JMeter DSL project](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/) which provides easy and handy way of creating a JMeter test plan, however it doesn't fully support all the features. For basic test plans it should be faster and easier than point 2
4. There is [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/) which provides [possibility to create JMeter scripts in a declarative manner using YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config) and [YAML naturally supports comments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_comments.htm)